# keras resume training with different learning rate

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I built a simple LSTM model using keras and trained as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(activation='tanh',input_dim=6,output_dim=50,return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=1,activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer =optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.01),metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=256,nb_epoch=1000,validation_data = (X_test,y_test))
model.save('model_params.h5')
```

The model almost converged. Therefore I want to fine tune the model by resuming training using smaller learning rate (i.e., 0.001). How could I achieve this?

Comment: When you `save` a keras model, it saves the state of the optimizer too. Just check the `load_model` code and you will find a workaround it

Comment: @Nain I know. But I want to change the optimizer (its learning rate) itself. I wonder if need to reconstruct the model and compile the model, using the previous model's parameter to initialize it.

Comment: Yeap you need to compile it again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**New answer**

If your optimizer has an `lr` property, and this property is a tensor, you can change it with:

```
keras.backend.set_value(model.optimizer.lr, new_value)
```

**Old answer, with some side effects**

You just need to compile the model again:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer= optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),...)
```

But usually, `Adam` is a very good optimizer and doesn't need those changes. It's normal for it to find alone its ways.

It's very normal for the training to diverge when you compile with a new optimizer. It takes a few epochs until the optimizer adjusts itself.

Comment: Thanks. But as a new user I don't know how to mark it as answered. Where  can I find the button?

Comment: This is true, but I wonder how to avoid lost time until loss become as it was before.

I guess that if I would use the same LR as before that loss would immediately suffer after initiating new optimiser.

Probably related to internal variables in optimiser.

Comment: I updated the answer, it's better. You can also explore the concept of `decay`, many optimizers accept a `decay` argument that decreases the `lr` gradually during training.